# Is it true that $d((f+g)(x), (f+g)(y)) \leq d(f(x),f(y)) + d(g(x),g(y))$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

In arbitrary metric space $(M, d)$, is it true that $d((f+g)(x), (f+g)(y)) \leq d(f(x),f(y)) + d(g(x),g(y))$?

Clearly, in the simple case where $M = \mathbb{R}$ and $d(x,y) = | x - y |$, we have
$$\begin{align}
d((f+g)(x), (f+g)(y)) &= |(f+g)(x) - (f+g)(y)| \\
&= |(f(x) + g(x)) - (f(y) + g(y))| \\
&= |(f(x) - f(y)) + (g(x) - g(y))| \tag{1} \\
&\leq |f(x) - f(y)| + |g(x) - g(y)| \\
&= d(f(x), f(y)) + d(g(x), g(y)),
\end{align}$$
as desired. So basically, this proof requires the ability to rearrange the values within the absolute values sign, as indicated in line (1), which is certainly possible.

But when I try this same type of proof using just the properties of an arbitrary metric, I get
$$\begin{align}
d((f+g)(x), (f+g)(y)) &= d(f(x) + g(x), f(y) + g(y)) \\
&(=?) \ |d(f(x), f(y)) -  d(g(x), g(y))| \tag{2}\\
&\leq d(f(x),f(y)) + d(g(x), g(y)),
\end{align}$$

and I'm not sure I can do the same type of rearrangement in an arbitrary metric space, which is why I've put the question mark in line (2). I feel like I'm missing something obvious! (For what it's worth, I'm trying to use this to prove that the sum of uniformly continuous functions is uniformly continuous.)

Comment: is $M$ a vector space? if it isn't, then how is addition defined over it?

Comment: The question is not at all clear. What are the domains and codomains of $f$ and $g$? You need  a metric space in which sum is defined. I think the inequality is true if $d$ is a  translation invariant metric in a group, but false in general.

Comment: The question I am working on is from page 116 of Real Analysis by Carothers. The question is, "Show that the sum of uniformly continuous maps is uniformly continuous." There is an additional instruction that, "Except where noted, $M$ is an arbitrary metric space with metric $d$." So that's all the information I have to work with.

Comment: In that book, the sum of functions is defined for functions $f:M \to \Bbb R$, so that's probably the context for this problem. You should begin by making sure you understand what objects are you working with.

Comment: Are you sure about page 116? I look at 2000 publishing year and at page 116 are exercises 44-59, but which one you are speaking about?

Answer (score 1):

Its easy to show that the theorem holds when the metric is induced by a norm(as you showed). Consider the discrete metric $d(x,y)=1 \iff x=y$ and $0$ otherwise on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f(x)=g(y)=1$, $f(y)=g(x)=2$. Then
$$\text{LHS}=d(1+2,1+2)=1\\
  \text{RHS}=d(1,2)+d(2,1)=0$$